# why I am not getting current session in my repository class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have my service class annotated with @Service and its methods annotated with @Transnational , I am autowiring repository class into my service class and my service class in my controller. Autowiring is working fine but the problem is when i am trying to get current hibernate session in my repository class, it throws exception as no session for current thread.
Although when I create bean in xml using bean tag it works fine.
Any suggestions what might be going wrong?

Comment: have you enabled annotation driven transaction management in the application? ex `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`

Comment: yes I have, Transaction is working fine when i create the bean in xml.

Comment: You need to make the impl @Transactional rather than the interface if that's what you've done. Also code snippets are always useful.

Comment: Monkjack, @Transactional are applied to impl only.

Comment: Arun, I have not given transaction-manager = "transactionManager" in annotation-driven tag. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Post some code to show what is going on. It sounds like Hibernate session object is not being created, show your autowire for hibernate session and .xml files